# String.contains(otherString) gives "unexpected type"

Tags: java, string, contains, bluej

```
String doubleSpace = "  ";
String news = "The cat jumped.  The dog did not.";

while (news.contains(doubleSpace) = true)
{
    news=news.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

The above will not compile, giving the error "unexpected type. required:variable, found:value"
I do not understand why, as String.contains() should return a boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace) = true)
```

should be

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace) == true)
```

= is for assignment

== is for checking condition.

Answer (score 0):

your while loop is wrong,do like as below.You are assigning by using assignment value so you are getting that error.And also no need to compare with true because the `contains(...)` function itself will return true or false as you needed.

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace))
{
    news=news.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation error

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace) = true)
```

should be

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace) == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

the method .contains() on string already returns boolean
so you should not apply comparison

anyways if you do apply apply boolean operator '==' not '='

so your code can be
while (news.contains(doubleSpace) == true)

```
{
    news=news.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```

or more precisely

```
while (news.contains(doubleSpace))
{
    news=news.replaceAll("  ", " ");
}
```